# C# : How couroutine stop the loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to understand the concept of `coroutine` i don't know why code stop at when it `print 1,2,3`.But in this code loop should run 30 times and print value 1 to 30.

```
public class NewCore : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine (MyCoroutine (0.52f));
        StartCoroutine (CoroutineKiller (2f));
    }

    IEnumerator MyCoroutine (float delay)
    {
        int value = 0;
        while (value < 30)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (delay);//wait
            value ++;
            print (value);
        }

        StartCoroutine (MyCoroutine (delay));
    }

    IEnumerator CoroutineKiller (float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (delay);
        StopAllCoroutines ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing values from 1 - 30 with delay of 0.52sec, but after 2 seconds you stop doing so (you call `StopAllCoroutines`). Which is why you are only seeing 1, 2 and 3 printed out.

Try to comment out `StartCoroutine (CoroutineKiller (2f));`, or give it more delay to see how it controls the flow stop.

---

Coroutines are similar to threads - although not really - but yes in the sense that calling `StartCoroutine` does not block the code.

So when you're doing this:

```
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine (MyCoroutine (0.52f));
    StartCoroutine (CoroutineKiller (2f));
}
```

It will actually start both coroutines and execute them step by step, side by side, on each Update call.

If you wish to execute the coroutines one after another, try the following:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(F());
}

IEnumerator F()
{
    // by yielding the Coroutine, it will block the execution of
    // this coroutine (F) until MyCoroutine finishes
    yield return StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(1.52f));

    // This is no longer doing much, really.
    yield return StartCoroutine(Killer(2f));

    print("done");
}
```

You can read more about the [Execution Order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) which also includes information about coroutines and how the yield system actually works.

Comment: but at start() method `StartCoroutine (MyCoroutine (0.52f)` execution will first run then the second method `StartCoroutine (CoroutineKiller (2f))` will run.How does it automatically stop the couroutine when 2seconds happen

Comment: @cenkisabi i don't know how the code knows when 2second completed it stop the `coroutine` it jumps to that method `StartCoroutine (CoroutineKiller (2f))`

Comment: You mean yield return run wait for next exectuion And `StartCoroutine ()`run parallel

Comment: StartCoroutine will run in "parallel", but you can yield it in order to wait for it. However you cannot yield in the `Start` or `Update` themselves, AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

It seems you using StopCoroutine(MyCoroutine()); in CoroutineKiller and it stops coroutine after 2 seconds. (your parameter is 2f. And I think you used it for WaitForSeconds). So your MyCoroutine function working just 3 delay ( 0.52 + 0.52 + 0.52 =1.56) and before fourth delay ends, you stop this coroutine and you get just 1,2,3 printed.